# Sending MIDI control message via 64 bit Delphi

Tags: delphi, controls, message, midi

The need is to send out a midi message like 91.17.00 in Delphi. There is a package midiio-master on GitHub that works fine for both input and output in 32 bit. The input function also works in 64 bit, but not the output. An exception is thrown when you try to set the output device. There is a new package out, 'NativeMidi' that appears to have 64 bit functions, but there is no documentation or examples and I can't figure out how to use it. Either fixing midiio-master or an example of NativeMidi control output would be a great help.

Comment: What is EXACTLY the exception that is thrown? Show the source code around where the exception occurs. Edit your message to add the information.

Comment: Welcome to the internet - it works thru links. Please link to "_package midiio-master on GitHub_" and "_a new package out, 'NativeMidi'_" as then not every reader has to figure it out himself and we're also looking at really the same code.

Comment: I hope you do understand that nobody can help you solve your problem unless you show the code you are having problems with. So, please show the code you are using to send the midi message, including variable declarations. Also, as others have requested, show the code that triggers the exception and repeat the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved with a change to the module `Midiout.pas` in the `midiio-master` package.

Line 580 that says

```
for TestDeviceID := -1 to (MidiOutGetNumDevs - 1) do
```

needs to be changed to

```
for TestDeviceID := 0 to (MidiOutGetNumDevs - 1) do
```

In 32-bit world, the `-1` triggers a test to see if any Midi interfaces are present, but fails in 64-bit.

After unzipping the package, create a subfolder for 64-bit source and copy all the `.pas` files into it. Change the library file reference in Tools > Options > Language > Delphi Options > Library accordingly. That way you can have two versions of `Midiout.pas`.

Comment: Then it's most likely about [beNative midiio](https://github.com/beNative/midiio/blob/master/MidiOut.pas#L580).